# Modal transition via presentViewController:animated ignores the animation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, presentmodalviewcontroller, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to display a QLpreviewcontroller on a UIVIewcontroller.

```
-(void)showPreview{

   if(!_previewController){
        _previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
        _previewController.dataSource = self;
        _previewController.delegate = self;
    }

    // There will always be one item here
    _previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;

    [_previewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentViewController:_previewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

the previecontroller is displayed but the transition is not animated. it just appears without any animation.

Comment: How are you calling this method? Is it possible that you're not calling it from the main thread?

Comment: its a method called via IBAction. If this method is called via any other thread it won't display Previewcontroller at all.

Comment: Is there is something else you are doing like showing or dismissing alert/actionsheet or hiding or showing keyboard.